# Gridview in a Tooltip

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

Is there a way to display a gridview in a tooltip?

Answer (score 2):

In the standard tooltip no, but you'd have to write your own tool tip class to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery you could do this using the [QTip Plugin](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)
.

Answer (score 1):

I use QTip in a lot of apps, but I'm not sure this is the best solution.....it's a lot of overhead if this is all you're using it for, and it's really very straightforward to do it from scratch.  I'd treat it as a simple tab pane that is toggled by Jquery, using a $(element).show() to make it show.

Here's a tut along those lines: http://spyrestudios.com/how-to-create-a-sexy-vertical-sliding-panel-using-jquery-and-css3/

As an aside, while I know .net has some gridviews available, I'm in love with additional functionality that [datatables](http://www.datatables.net) provides.  Far and away, this is the one JQuery plugin that my clients cite as adding true value to their apps.

Answer (score 1):

i am using VS2010 and in VS 2012 intellisense  is showing tooltip option in Designer page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ModalPopup to achieve it and use JavaScript to show it dynamically.
Please try the below sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getTop(e)
    { 
        var offset=e.offsetTop; 
        if(e.offsetParent!=null) offset+=getTop(e.offsetParent);
        return offset; 
    } 
    function getLeft(e)
    { 
        var offset=e.offsetLeft; 
        if(e.offsetParent!=null) offset+=getLeft(e.offsetParent);
        return offset; 
    } 
    function hideModalPopupViaClient()
    {
        var modalPopupBehavior = $find('ModalPopupExtender');
        modalPopupBehavior.hide();
    }
    function showModalPopupViaClient(control,id) {


        $get("inputBox").innerText="You choose the item "+control.innerHTML;

        var modalPopupBehavior = $find('ModalPopupExtender');
        modalPopupBehavior.show();           
        $get(modalPopupBehavior._PopupControlID).style.left=getLeft($get('<%=DataList1.ClientID %>'))+ $get('<%=DataList1.ClientID %>').offsetWidth+"px";
        $get(modalPopupBehavior._PopupControlID).style.top=getTop(control)+"px";            

    }
```

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server" ID="ScriptManager1" />
<input id="Hidden1" runat="server" type="hidden" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>    
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
    <ItemTemplate>     
        <div style="border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>  
            <asp:HyperLink ID="detail" runat="server" onmouseout="hideModalPopupViaClient()" onmouseover="showModalPopupViaClient(this)">'<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>'</asp:HyperLink>
        </div>  
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>        
    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"         SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Categories]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="showModalPopupClientButton" style="display:none"/>

    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender" runat="server"             TargetControlID="showModalPopupClientButton"
        PopupControlID="programmaticPopup"             RepositionMode="None" 
        />
    <br />

    <div CssClass="modalPopup" id="programmaticPopup" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;      filter:alpha(opacity=70);opacity:0.7;display:none;width:50px;padding:10px">
        <span id="inputBox" ></span>


       <br />
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the tooltip in ASP.net grid view. See the below code, which should be included in the `GridView1_RowDataBound` event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++) {
            e.Row.Cells[i].ToolTip = GridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText;
        }
    }
}
```